# creating an advanced metronome in WPF (problems with code created animation and completed event)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, timer

Good afternoon,

over the last few weeks I have been working on a project to create an advanced metronome.  the metronome is made up of the following things

1. a swinging arm
2. a light flash
3. a collection of dynamically created user controls that represent beats (4 of them that are either on, accented or off).
4. a usercontrol that displays an LCD numeric display and calculates the number of milliseconds between beats for the selected BPM (60000/BPM=milliseconds)

the user selects a BPM and presses start and the following happens

1. the arm swings between two angles at a rate of n milliseconds per sweep
2. the light flashes at the end of each arm sweep
3. the indicators are created and they flash in sequence (one at the end of each sweep).

now the problem
the Arm and light flash animation are created in code and added to a story board with repeat forever and auto reverse.

the indicators are created in code and need to fire an event at the end of each Arm sweep animation.

So, what I did after much messing around was create a timer that runs at the same pace as the storyboard.

the problem, over 30 seconds the timer and the storyboard go out of sync and therefore the indicators and the arm sweep are not in time (not good for a metronome!!).

I was trying to catch the completed event of the animations and use that as a trigger to stop and restart the timer, this was all I could come up with to keep the two in perfect sync.

the moving out of sync is caused by the storyboard slipping and the fact that the storyboard is invoked with begin on the line before the timer is invoked with .start, this although microseconds I think means that they start impossibly close but not at exactly the same time.

my question, 
when I try to bind to the completed event of the animation it never fires.  I was under the impression that completed even fires regardless of autoreverse (i.e in between each iteration).  is this not the case?

can anyone think of another (more cunning) way to keep the two things in sync.

lastly, I did look to see if I could fire a method from a storyboard (which would of made my life really easy, however it would appear that this cannot be done).

if there are any suggestions I am not precious, I just want to get this finished!!

final point of interest,
the bpm can be adjusted whilst the metronome is running, this is achieved by calculating the millisecond duration on the fly (mouse down of a button) and scale the storyboard by the difference between the current speed and the new speed.  obviously the timer running the indicators has to be changed at the same time (using interval).

code below is from my project so far (not the XAML just the C#)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;    

namespace MetronomeLibrary
{    
    public partial class MetronomeLarge
    {
        private bool Running;

        //Speed and time signature
        private int _bpm = 60;
        private int _beats = 4;
        private int _beatUnit = 4;
        private int _currentBeat = 1;
        private readonly int _baseSpeed = 60000 / 60;
        private readonly DispatcherTimer BeatTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        private Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

        public MetronomeLarge()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NumericDisplay.Value = BPM;

            BeatTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);

            SetUpAnimation();    
            SetUpIndicators(); 
        }

        public int Beats
        {
            get
            {
                return _beats;
            }
            set
            {
                _beats = value;
                SetUpIndicators();
            }
        }

        public int BPM
        {
            get
            {
                return _bpm;
            }
            set
            {
                _bpm = value;
                //Scale the story board here
                SetSpeedRatio();
            }
        }

        public int BeatUnit
        {
            get
            {
                return _beatUnit;
            }
            set
            {
                _beatUnit = value;
            }
        }

        private void SetSpeedRatio()
        {
            //divide the new speed (bpm by the old speed to get the new ratio)
            float newMilliseconds = (60000 / BPM);
            float newRatio = _baseSpeed / newMilliseconds;
            storyboard.SetSpeedRatio(newRatio);

            //Set the beat timer according to the beattype (standard is quarter beats for one sweep of the metronome
            BeatTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(newMilliseconds);
        }

        private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MetronomeBeat(_currentBeat);

            _currentBeat++;

            if (_currentBeat > Beats)
            {
                _currentBeat = 1;
            }
        }

        private void MetronomeBeat(int Beat)
        {
                //turnoff all indicators
                TurnOffAllIndicators();

                //Find a control by name
                MetronomeLargeIndicator theIndicator = (MetronomeLargeIndicator)gridContainer.Children[Beat-1];

                //illuminate the control
                theIndicator.TurnOn();
                theIndicator.PlaySound();    
        }

        private void TurnOffAllIndicators()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= gridContainer.Children.Count-1; i++)
            {
                MetronomeLargeIndicator theIndicator = (MetronomeLargeIndicator)gridContainer.Children[i];
                theIndicator.TurnOff();
            }
        }

        private void SetUpIndicators()
        {
            gridContainer.Children.Clear();
            gridContainer.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

            for (int i = 1; i <= _beats; i++)
            {
                MetronomeLargeIndicator theNewIndicator = new MetronomeLargeIndicator();

                ColumnDefinition newCol = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto };
                gridContainer.ColumnDefinitions.Add(newCol);
                gridContainer.Children.Add(theNewIndicator);
                theNewIndicator.Name = "Indicator" + i.ToString();
                Grid.SetColumn(theNewIndicator, i - 1);
            }
        }   

        private void DisplayOverlay_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleAnimation();
        }

        private void ToggleAnimation()
        {
            if (Running)
            {
                //stop the animation
                ((Storyboard)Resources["Storyboard"]).Stop() ;
                BeatTimer.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                //start the animation
                BeatTimer.Start();
                ((Storyboard)Resources["Storyboard"]).Begin();
                SetSpeedRatio();                 
            }

            Running = !Running;
        }


        private void ButtonIncrement_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NumericDisplay.Value++;
            BPM = NumericDisplay.Value;
        }

        private void ButtonDecrement_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NumericDisplay.Value--;
            BPM = NumericDisplay.Value;
        }

        private void ButtonIncrement_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageBrush theBrush = new ImageBrush() 
            { 
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new 
                    Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MetronomeLibrary;component/Images/pad-metronome-increment-button-over.png")) 
            };
            ButtonIncrement.Background = theBrush;
        }

        private void ButtonIncrement_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageBrush theBrush = new ImageBrush() 
            { 
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new 
                    Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MetronomeLibrary;component/Images/pad-metronome-increment-button.png")) 
            };
            ButtonIncrement.Background = theBrush;
        }

        private void ButtonDecrement_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageBrush theBrush = new ImageBrush() 
            { 
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new 
                    Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MetronomeLibrary;component/Images/pad-metronome-decrement-button-over.png")) 
            };
            ButtonDecrement.Background = theBrush;
        }

        private void ButtonDecrement_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageBrush theBrush = new ImageBrush() 
            { 
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new 
                    Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MetronomeLibrary;component/Images/pad-metronome-decrement-button.png")) 
            };
            ButtonDecrement.Background = theBrush;
        }

        private void SweepComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BeatTimer.Stop();
            BeatTimer.Start();
        }

        private void SetUpAnimation()
        {
            NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());
            RegisterName(Arm.Name, Arm);

            DoubleAnimation animationRotation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = -17,
                To = 17,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(NumericDisplay.Milliseconds)),
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
                AccelerationRatio = 0.3,
                DecelerationRatio = 0.3,
                AutoReverse = true,                 
            };

            Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(animationRotation, 90);

            MetronomeFlash.Opacity = 0;

            DoubleAnimation opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = 1.0,
                To = 0.0,
                AccelerationRatio = 1,
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(NumericDisplay.Milliseconds - 0.5),
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)),
            };

            Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(opacityAnimation, 10);

            storyboard.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(NumericDisplay.Milliseconds * 2));
            storyboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animationRotation, Arm);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationRotation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimation, MetronomeFlash);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));    
            storyboard.Children.Add(animationRotation);
            storyboard.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);

            Resources.Add("Storyboard", storyboard);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your application might be a candidate for [per-frame animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970492.aspx). See this doc on [frame-based rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838.aspx).

Comment: I'm writing a similar animation with DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames at the moment. When I have finished it myself, I will have a look if that could be suiting for you.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be easily implemented with WPF animations. Instead, a good method would be a [game loop](http://google.com/search?q=game+loop). A little research should turn up lots of resources about this. The first one that jumped out at me was http://www.nuclex.org/articles/3-basics/5-how-a-game-loop-works.

In your game loop, you would follow one or the other of these basic procedures:

- Calculate how much time has elapsed since the last frame.
- Move your displays appropriately.

or

- Calculate the current time.
- Position your displays appropriately.

The advantage of a game loop is that although the timing may drift slightly (depending on what sort of timing you use), all displays will drift by the same amount.

You can prevent clock drift by calculating time by the system clock, which for practical purposes does not drift. Timers do drift, because they do not run by the system clock.

Answer (score 1):

Time sync is a vaster field than you'd think.

I suggest you take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) which is renowned for scheduling/timers issues.

Syncing a WPF animation is tricky because Storyboards are not part of the logical tree, therefore you can't bind anything in them.
That's why you can't define dynamic/variable Storyboards in XAML, you have to do it in C# as you did.

I suggest you make 2 Storyboards: one for the tick to the left, the other one to the right.
In between each animation, fire a method to do your calculations/update another part of the UI, but do it in a separate `Task` so that the timings aren't messed up (a few µs for the calculations make up for quite some time after 30s already!)
Keep in mind that you will need to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` from your `Task` to update the UI.

And lastly, at least set the `Task` flag `TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness` so that Tasks run in the order they were started.
Now since that just gives a hint to the `TaskScheduler` and doesn't guarantees them to run in order, you may want to use a queueing system instead for full guarantee.

HTH,

Bab.

Answer (score 0):

You could try 2 animations , one for the right swing and one for the left.  In the animation complete on each, start the other animation (checking for cancellation flags) and update your indicators (possibly via BeginInvoke on the Dispatcher so you don't interfere with the next animation start.)

Answer (score 0):

I think getting the timer to sync with an animation is difficult - it is a dispatcher based timer which is based on messages - sometimes it can skip a bit of time, ie if you click fast with the mouse a lot I think the animation timer also is dispatcher based, so they will easily get out of sync.

I would suggest to abandon the syncing and let the timer handle it. Can't you let it update a property with notification and let your metronome arm position bind to that?
To get the accelaration/deceleration you just have to use a Sine or Cosine function.

Comment: You could let your actual positions be based on the system time then you can get skips in animation but it will be the right place and never get out of sync.